# Dualboot Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 14.04 No Windows Bootloader on grub2

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, wine, grub-efi

So, I had Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu running fine on my laptop until Ubuntu updated to 14.10, after that Ubuntu could not load, just a Purple Screen and a Blinking CapsLock Key, so I booted into Windows and created one more time a bootable flashdrive and everything to re install Ubuntu 14.04, and it did but now it only shows me the option to boot on Ubuntu, NO WINDOWS OPTION. My questions are...

How can I repair my dual boot My system is not able to boot in Windows?

How can I run windows programs In Ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: You can check whether Windows loader is getting detected by Ubuntu or not using the command 'os-prober'. If yes, then proceed with the answer by `UTF-8`, otherwise you need to recover/recreate Windows boot files.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if Windows still is installed. If you deleted Windows when installing Ubuntu, you will have to reinstall Windows.

Boot Ubuntu, open a terminal.

```
$ df -h
```

In the column "mounted on" there is one entry with only a slash (/). Look at what's in the "filesystem" column of that row. It's something like /dev/sda6 or /dev/sda1.

Then enter this:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Make sure not to write the number in the end.

This will reinstall grub. The command line output also will inform you about which systems have been found.